# Outputting Custom Post type Data into Table, Without having multiple Table tags

Tags: php, wordpress

Im attempting to output a list of places from a post type into a table that has a heading with the area in which its located to separate them. The issue being that the loop generates a table for each instance which I dont want so I tried to use a nested If to stop that but the output is correct for the first instance of the loop but then just randomly outputs the data ont the page for the rest.

The Idea:

```php
<?php
 $x = 0;
 $service = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'places', 'posts_per_page'=>'-1', 
 'order_by' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC'));
 if($service->have_posts()) : while ($service->have_posts()) : $service->the_post();
?>
 <?php
    if(in_category('place-x')){
 ?>
        <?php if($x < 1){   ?>
            <h3>place-x</h3>
            <table style="width:100%">
        
            <tr>
                <th>Place</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Viewers</th> 
            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php the_title()?></td>
                 <td><?php types_render_field("address");?></td>
                <td><?php types_render_field("marker-description");?></td>
              </tr>
        
    <?php if($x < 1){   ?>
        </table>
        
    <?php 
            }
    } $x++ ?>
<?php  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Small note: There is to much involved here for me to make a snippet I can run and still accurately get a answer

The Result:

[image]

**Am I Approaching this incorrectly? Or am I missing something extremely obvious?**

> Seems to me like it doesnt know to add the other items into that table, But if I move my logic around a bit I end up with 20 different tables which is not what I want either, I thought that this would output multiple `<tr>` into that table but it seems my approach is flawed

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it, The interaction is a bit interesting.

For one the Nested If's dont seem to know where to close the table.
I'm resolving this in a very dirty method by having multiple loops each looking for that individual category.

Then it seems the biggest culprit is the `</table>` being closed before the loop ends this has to occur after the endif; for some reason. Id love to know why.

**I wont be accepting my own answer as this isnt so much as a solution but rather a patchwork. Despite it working. I would like to know why this is happening**

```php
  <?php
    
     $service = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'places', 'category_name' => 'place-x', 'posts_per_page'=>'-1', 'order_by' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC'));
     if($service->have_posts()) : while ($service->have_posts()) : $service->the_post();
    ?>
            <?php if($x++ == 0){   ?>
                <h3>place-x</h3>
                <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Mall</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Viewers</th> 
                </tr>
            <?php }; ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php the_title()?></td>
                 <td><?php echo  types_render_field("address");?></td>
                <td><?php echo types_render_field("marker-description");?></td>
              </tr>
    
<?php  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </table>
```